# Paging Gmails Atom feed

Tags: pagination, oauth-2.0, gmail, paging, atom-feed

I am currently working on a JS application using OAuth 2.0 to access the gmail atom feed https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/ I am able to successfully sign the request, and retrieve the emails, however I am only able to access the first 20.  Is there any way to access more than 20 emails in this feed?  If not, is there any way using a different feed?

Thanks
-A

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that as he atom only provides access to the very latest 20 unread messages